# Spring Security target url redirects to application context on live server

Tags: spring, apache, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security

After implementing Spring Security in my application, in Local Server it redirects correctly.

But After hosting it in live server, it takes application context along with the redirect target url.

Example: 
After Username and Password were specified,

it redirects to:
`http://www.example.com/example/j_spring_security_check`

instead of 
`http://www.example.com/j_spring_security_check`

How to resolve it?

All other pages to `http://www.example.com/` works fine.

Application hosted with Apache Tomcat and Apache httpd server.

Comment: What is the deployment root path of your app? example? And also add config where you are redirecting.

Comment: I deployed in Tomcat. `www.example.com:8080/example/j_spring_security_check` works fine. But `www.example.com/j_spring_secuirty_check` is not working. Where to add config for redirecting just **j_spring_security_check**?

Comment: I deployed by Tomcat Manager GUI. Its deployed in **webapps** directory.

Comment: This is the correct behaviour. You need to deploy the application in the root context - eg rename the artifact to 'ROOT.war' and deploy it.

Comment: I have two applications deployed in the same server. Can't we do anything within ? May I know why `login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"` alone redirects to context while every other things are working fine.,

Comment: you could implement your own `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Comment: I tried. Nothing works out. After username and password where specified, it calls `http://www.example.com:8080/example/j_spring_security_check` it's not working in `http://www.example.com/j_spring_security_check`.. All other things are working fine.

Comment: I renamed the artifact to ROOT.war and deployed it. Now I get sign-in correctly. But after sign out, not able to sign in again., subsequent sign-in shows error `Invalid CSRF Token`